# Generated subview is always behind image view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

viewController.m

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self addScoreRowViewWithIndexLeft:(++i) andName:[scoreDict objectForKey:@"name"] andScore:[[scoreDict objectForKey:@"points"] integerValue]];
}

-(void) addScoreRowViewWithIndexLeft:(NSInteger)index andName: (NSString *)name andScore: (NSInteger)score {

    UIView *scoreRowView   = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(128, 112 + index * 80, 280, 20)];

    UILabel *indexLabel    = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20)];

    UILabel *nameLabel     = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 20, 180, 20)];

    UILabel *scoreLabel    = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(330, 20, 50, 20)];

    UIColor *color = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    [indexLabel setText:[@((int)index) stringValue]];
    [indexLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DINAlternate-Bold" size:18]];
    [indexLabel setTextColor:color];

    [nameLabel setText:name];
    [nameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DINAlternate-Bold" size:18]];
    [nameLabel setTextColor:color];

    [scoreLabel setText:[@((int)score) stringValue]];
    [scoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DINAlternate-Bold" size:18]];
    [scoreLabel setTextColor:color];

    [scoreRowView addSubview:indexLabel];
    [scoreRowView addSubview:nameLabel];
    [scoreRowView addSubview:scoreLabel];

    [self.view addSubview:scoreRowView];
}
```

I added my ImageView in my Storyboard as a subview of my View.

When I delete the ImageView, everything is ok. I get displayed my other code generated subviews. But when I add the ImageView in my Storyboard, it's on top of my other subviews. If I give my ImageView an alpha of 0.3 I can see my subviews shining through.

What's wrong with my code? I also tried;

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:scoreRowView];
```

but it doesn't work.

What can I do?

Comment: first question is why do you have 2 subviews on top of each other?

Comment: Have you tried setting the z position of image view to be behind like this?

    `view.layer.zPosition = -1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change zPosition of your ImageView and scoreRowView. You can do this this way:

1. Connect your ImageView with your ViewController
2. In bottom of ViewDidLoad add something like that:

   ```
   yourImageView.layer.zPosition = 1;
   scoreRowView.layer.zPosition = 2;
   ```

I'm suspecting that `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:scoreRowView];` doesn't work because you invoke it in ViewDidLoad where view in not fully work. You can try to invoke it in e.g. ViewDidAppear and check if that will work.

Comment: thanks is working! a little question: how can i center my nameLabel in my scoreRowView?

Comment: First of all I would strongly recommended using autolayouts instead of create your view in code ;). Anyway you need to set proper textAligment on your nameLabel like this: [textAligment setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];  Then you need to set proper center in your frame. It should looks something like this: nameLabel.center = CGPointMake(scoreRowView.center.x, nameLabel.center.y). There could be some mistake because I can't test it right now but it's should works